Can I have Apple Pay and Google Pay button to invoke an API call before presenting payment sheet?
I have an e-commerce app and I am trying to integrate Apple Pay and Google Pay in it.
For validation reason, I want to invoke an endpoint first on tap of Apple/Google Pay button before the user is presented with the pay sheet.
Is it something allowed and won't lead to app rejection while the app is in review ?
